# Twig Navigation done right (appending variables to render)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I was trying to get a navigation to work in symfony using twig. It didn't work as I expected. I want a service or another controller to provide the navigation.items, so I don't have to include it in every response object. So that if I'd render like this:

```
...
    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('title' => $slug));
}
```

I would be able to include this:

```
{# app/src/Acme/Bundle/AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/views/Navigation/navigation.html.twig #}
<nav>
    <ul>
        {% for item in navigation.items %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url(item.action) }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li>The menu is empty.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement KnpMenuBundle: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle

This bundle does everything you ask.

The docs describe a simple implementation: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: I know it does everything I ask, I just want to do it myself, so I can learn Symfony2 and Twig.